# How to check if $1 is x or y in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do this thing like `if $1 is x or y then do this` and here's how I'm trying to do it;

```
if [ "$1" = "x|y|z"]; then
  echo "I'm $1"
else
  echo "I'm $1"
fi
```

so if `$1` is `x` or `y` or `z`, it will do this and else do that. `$1` is the command line argument here like `./test.sh x` or `./test.sh y`

But apparently, this doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [ "$1" = "x" ] || [ "$1" = "y" ] ; then
    echo "....."
fi
```

if you would like to use regex match, you can check the `=~` usage.

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer! can you tell me what's regex match and should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using "case":

```
#!/bin/bash
while test $# -gt 0
do
    case "$1" in
        --param1) echo "Param 1"
            ;;
        --param2) echo "Param 2"
            ;;
        *) echo "other param $1"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: This isn't tailored to the question. Where did you copy it from?